Calculus of variations with linear Lagrangian and two optimisations
I am working on a two-part system, that jointly determines two functions $F$ and $G$. $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $G'(x) = g(x)$. $F$ and $G$ are both defined on $[0, 1]$, $F(0) = G(0) = 0$, they are both non-decreasing and $F(1) = G(1) = 1$.
$F$ is such that the following is maximised:
$$Q_1 = \int_0^1 f(x)[G(x) - x]dx$$
$G$ is such that the following is maximised
$$Q_2 = \int_0^1 g(x)[F(x) - 2x]dx$$
Approach 1
Trying the first one, I see that the integrand is linear in $f$. Therefore, I can make $f$ a Dirac-delta function with all the weight on $\arg \max_{x\in[0, 1]} (G(x) - x)$ to get my maximum. Differentiating and setting equal to zero, this gives all weight where, $g(x) = 1$.
Similarly, I can make $g$ the Dirac-delta function with all weight on $\arg \max_{x\in[0, 1]} (F(x) - 2x)$. Differentiating and setting to zero again, this gives all the weight where $f(x) = 2$.
I am stuck after this and do not know how to proceed formally. I have a feeling that the solution would be of this form, where $x_0 \in [0, 1]$,
$$f(x) = g(x) = \delta(x - x_0)$$
I am not sure how to reconcile the fact that $f(x)$ is supposed to be 2 at its maxima and $g(x)$ is supposed to be 1.
Approach 2
I also took an alternative approach. Suppose I use the Euler-Lagrange equation, taking into account the constraints.
$$Q_1^* = \int_0^1 f(x) [G(x) - x]dx - \lambda_1 (\int_0^1 f(x) dx - 1)$$
This would give
$$G(x) - x = \lambda_1$$
As $G(0) = 0$, this gives $\lambda_1 = 0$. As $G(1) = 1$, this gives, $\lambda_1 = 0$. This checks out. Therefore,
$$G(x) = x$$
On the other hand,
$$Q_2^* = \int_0^1 g(x) [F(x) - 2x]dx - \lambda_2 (\int_0^1 g(x) dx - 1)$$
This gives
$$F(x) - 2x = \lambda_2$$
As $F(0) = 0$, we have $\lambda_2 = 0$. As $F(1) = 1$, we have, $\lambda_2 = -1$. This seems to be a problem.
How do I proceed then?

As $G(x)-x\le 1-x$ the largest value of $Q_1$ is obtained when $G(x)\equiv 1$ and $f(x)=\delta(x)$. Similar for $Q_2$: $F(x)\equiv 1$ and $g(x)=\delta(x)$. These $F$ and $G$ do not agree with the initial condition, but they may be approximated by a suboptimal solution. Differentiating and setting the derivative to zero works only for unconstrained optimization, which is not the case here.

The constraint you added to your equation does not match the constraints in your original problem states. You are constraining $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$ when you want to impose boundary conditions and monotonicity.

@A.Γ. Thank you, this makes sense to me. Honestly, for the application I am working on, I am willing to give up $F(0)=G(0)=0$, instead just requiring these two to be non-negative, and then ig your idea would work directly.

@whpowell96 Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, this would not ensure $F(0) = G(0) = 0$. Actually, for the application I am working on, I want them to be valid cumulative dist functions, maybe I should have mentioned that clearly. So, I want them to be non-negative, and values at 1 to be 1. I wrote $F(0) = G(0) = 0$ as I thought that would be more convenient later on for me. But in case I want to go ahead with this, how do I incorporate these constraints?

If you define $f(x) = \exp(u(x))$ and $g(x) = \exp v(x)$ then this ensures the densities are positive. and that $F$ and $G$ are nondecreasing. Defining $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x)dx$ ensures $F(0)=0$ and the integral constraint on $f$ ensures $F(1)=1$.
